# Can I walk from Las Vegas McCarran Airport to UNLV?

Tags: airport-transfer, walking, las-vegas, las

I will be flying to Las Vegas for a conference at [UNLV](http://www.unlv.edu/).  The UNLV campus is adjacent to Las Vegas McCarran Airport (LAS), and it appears on [a map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/36.0900768,-115.1527913/Thomas+%26+Mack+Center/@36.0975998,-115.1568919,15z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xe0617b41c7bee19!2m2!1d-115.144252!2d36.104924!3e2) that the distance between them is about 1.5 miles.  This would be a reasonable walking distance, assuming there are sidewalks.

Is there a reasonable and safe walking route from the airport terminal to the UNLV campus?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging by Google maps (and street view) it looks feasible during the day, though there appear to be no sidewalks in the section between the terminal building and Paradise road. You would not be the first, if you see [this](https://www.google.ca/maps/@36.0940482,-115.1476759,3a,75y,23.41h,73.12t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s6ypf1HvkApbvSXTjrderWQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) view.

[image]

That said, it does not look like a very pleasant walk and might not be wise after dark. The 108 bus will bypass the part without sidewalks at the cost of $1.75 and a bit more time.